# How to access dictionary elements value from a Dictionary(Dictionary elements are dictionary itself)

Tags: python, loops, dictionary, nlp, senna

I have tokenized sentences from texts. Now on each tokenized sentences, I applied Senna Semantic Role Labeling.
`annotation.getAnnotations("He created the Robot")['srl']` is the function that returns a dictionary like `[{'A1': 'the Robot', 'A0': 'He', 'V': 'created'}]`
in D dictionary, single elements like A1 can be accessed using `D[0]['A1']`.

Now when assign this dictionary elements with a key as dictionary elements to another dictionary, then how can this dictionary elements be accessed with another dictionary. I have tried for multiple sentences in a loop for making it meaningful.

```
 j=0
 for i in tokenized_sentences:
     srl[j]= ann.getAnnotations(i)['srl']
     print(srl[j][0]['A0'])   # **not working, improvements can be here**
     j=j+1
```

I think this is not so tough questions, all that need to know the syntax and implementation. But I found no help in the internet.

Comment: You forgot parenthesis. It should be `print(srl[j][0]['A0'])`

Comment: Its okay now. But I need the solution. A help from you is welcomed.

Comment: Do you have an initialized `srl` array in the size of `len(tokenized_sentences)`?

Comment: srl is declared as srl={} and tokenized_sentences gets length dynamically on depend on text.I have done this sentences tokenization using nltk.

Comment: What is the actual error?

Comment: print (srl[j][0]['A0'])

IndexError: list index out of range

Comment: I have taken the function out of the loop and it works fine. srl = (ann.getAnnotations("He created the Robot")['srl'])
print(srl[0]['A0'])                    output: He

Comment: It seems that some of your sentences returns a blank list. This is probably the issue, since srl[j][0] will return an IndexError.